# Type conversion with scope resolution operator

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to create a callback function in my class, but I'm having an error of `Invalid Type Conversion`.

```
StaticWndProc = (WNDPROC)SetWindowLongPtr(staticcontrol, GWLP_WNDPROC, (LPARAM)MyClass::MyCallBack);
```

The callback function is

```
LRESULT CALLBACK MyClass::MyCallBack(HWND hwnd, UINT Message, WPARAM wparam, LPARAM lparam) { 
    ...
    return CallWindowProc(StaticWndProc, hwnd, Message, wparam, lparam); //v2
}
```

How can I possibly cast my callback to `LPARAM`?

Comment: `MyCallBack` must be a static function.

Comment: As an aside, it is recommended to use [SetWindowSubclass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-setwindowsubclass) rather than `SetWindowLongPtr` to subclass a window.

Comment: Avoid C-casts which hides your errors.

Comment: Should I really need to declare `MyCallBack` as static?

Comment: Yes, calling non-static functions requires passing this pointer. Nonstatic functions have __thiscall calling convention, CALLBACK is defined as __stdcall.
It's strange that you was able to compile a nonstatic function as CALLBACK without errors.